# react js form getting submitted twice

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs, spring-boot

I have below code which calls save form

```
           <div className="col-md-4">
              <button onClick={saveCredit}  className="btn btn-success">
                Submit
            </button>
```

I have onclick handler function as

```
 const saveCredit = () =>{
     //validate form
     // call api to save form attributes
     CreditTransactionDataService.create(data)
    .then(response => {
      setSubmitted(true);
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });

 }
```

after successful save , I will show successful message as below.

```
{submitted ? (
        <div>
          <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
          <button className="btn btn-success mr-2" onClick={newCreditTransaction}>
            Add
          </button><Link style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} className="btn btn-warning" to={"/creditTransactionList"}>
            return to List
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
```

but the problem is, my form is getting submitted twice, and creating duplicate records with same values.... couple of save options, i restricted with unique key column at database level, but few tables still need to handled at code level..

Comment: Does your form contain an `onSubmit` because if it does then it will be called twice when you click the submit button as you are also calling it in the `onClick`

Comment: there is no onSubmit in my form.. i only have onClick handler in the button tag

Comment: saveCredit is a block, isn't it supposed to be a function?

Answer (score 1):

Your button doesn't need `onClick` event handler if it's responsible for submitting a certain form. You should add `type="submit"` to `button` and `onSubmit` to `form` tag itself.

You should go for this approach to handle submitting correctly (clicking of the button or hitting enter by the user are covered).

Answer (score 1):

I´m unable to reproduce it in codepen, but one solution a little bit hacky could be check in the method if it is submitted already

```
 const saveCredit = {
     //Check if it is submitted
     if(!submitted){
     //validate form
     // call api to save form attributes
     CreditTransactionDataService.create(data)
    .then(response => {
      setSubmitted(true);
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
   }
 }
```

This may not be the best but could do the job

Also a thing I did notice is that your saveCredit function not look like a function.

Why not declare as an arrow function? Like:

```
const saveCredit = () => { //Your code }
```

Comment: it was typo... corrected now

Comment: did you suspect the link block is submitted the form again?